# flutter app crash when there is low or no network connection

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have this IconButton which when I press it updates a field on my cloud Firestore DB.I do not get any problem if there is a healthy internet connection, how ever is there is no network or low signal I get a timed out error and this causes the app to crash. I have have wraped the function in a try{} catch{} block but still that doesn't help.

```
 onPressed: (){
                 try{
                  Firestore.instance.runTransaction((Transaction thistransaction)async{
                  DocumentSnapshot docSnapshot = await thistransaction
                  .get(snapshotDocuments[index].reference);
                  await thistransaction.update(docSnapshot.reference,
                   {'voteUpBool':!docSnapshot['voteUpBool']});

                  });
                }
                 catch(err){
                    print(err.toString());
                  }
                 },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to check internet or wifi available or not for that just add **connectivity: ^0.3.1** dependency with latest version and follow the below code.

```
import 'dart:io';
...
try {
   final result = await InternetAddress.lookup('google.com');
   if (result.isNotEmpty && result[0].rawAddress.isNotEmpty) {
       print('connected');
   }
 } on SocketException catch (_) {
    print('not connected');
 }
```

Comment: I have put a print statement "internet is not working" to check the internet and I always get internet is not working

Comment: Have you added internet or wifi permissions in manifest file ?

Comment: Is there no other solution?
I find it strange that try catch does not work - and if I do a lot of Firebase calls, it will be a large overhead to have so many such calls. And also theoretically, if the connection is unstable - it could be that the InternetAddress.lookup will succeed but the Firebase will fail.