# flutter app crashes when internet gets disconnected while runnig transactions

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have asked a similar question [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52334397/flutter-app-crash-when-there-is-low-or-no-network-connection).The new problem is that, after the internet address lookup('connected' is printed), but while the transaction is being run if the network is disconnected or when the network is very slow I get a timed out error exception which causes the app to crash.

```
try {
   final result = await InternetAddress.lookup('google.com');
   if (result.isNotEmpty && result[0].rawAddress.isNotEmpty) {
       print('connected');
        Firestore.instance.runTransaction((transactionshere)async{
          DocumentReference reference =
            Firestore.instance.collection('One').document('two').collection('three').document('all_').collection('cur').document();
            await reference.setData(dataToSend,merge: true);

        });

   }
 } on SocketException catch (_) {
    print('not connected');
     _scafoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(
    SnackBar(content: Text("There was a problem check your connection"),duration: Duration(seconds: 4),),
     );
 }
```

`error output:`
`I/flutter (24149): connected
W/Firestore(24149): (0.6.6-dev) [Firestore]: The behavior for java.util.Date objects stored in Firestore is going to change AND YOUR APP MAY BREAK.
W/Firestore(24149): To hide this warning and ensure your app does not break, you need to add the following code to your app before calling any other Cloud Firestore methods:
W/Firestore(24149):
W/Firestore(24149): FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
W/Firestore(24149): FirebaseFirestoreSettings settings = new FirebaseFirestoreSettings.Builder()
W/Firestore(24149):     .setTimestampsInSnapshotsEnabled(true)
W/Firestore(24149):     .build();
W/Firestore(24149): firestore.setFirestoreSettings(settings);
W/Firestore(24149):
W/Firestore(24149): With this change, timestamps stored in Cloud Firestore will be read back as com.google.firebase.Timestamp objects instead of as system java.util.Date objects. So you will also need to update code expecting a java.util.Date to instead expect a Timestamp. For example:
W/Firestore(24149):
W/Firestore(24149): // Old:
W/Firestore(24149): java.util.Date date = snapshot.getDate("created_at");
W/Firestore(24149): // New:
W/Firestore(24149): Timestamp timestamp = snapshot.getTimestamp("created_at");
W/Firestore(24149): java.util.Date date = timestamp.toDate();
W/Firestore(24149):
W/Firestore(24149): Please audit all existing usages of java.util.Date when you enable the new behavior. In a future release, the behavior will be changed to the new behavior, so if you do not follow these steps, YOUR APP MAY BREAK.
I/zygote  (24149): The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
I/zygote  (24149): The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
V/NativeCrypto(24149): Registering com/google/android/gms/org/conscrypt/NativeCrypto's 287 native methods...
D/NetworkSecurityConfig(24149): No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
I/ProviderInstaller(24149): Installed default security provider GmsCore_OpenSSL
W/System  (24149): ClassLoader referenced unknown path: system/framework/mediatek-cta.jar
I/System.out(24149): e:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mediatek.cta.CtaHttp
W/System  (24149): ClassLoader referenced unknown path: system/framework/mediatek-cta.jar
I/System.out(24149): e:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mediatek.cta.CtaHttp
W/System  (24149): ClassLoader referenced unknown path: system/framework/mediatek-cta.jar
I/System.out(24149): e:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mediatek.cta.CtaHttp
W/System  (24149): ClassLoader referenced unknown path: system/framework/mediatek-cta.jar`

Comment: Please add the error output.

Comment: `Exception has occurred.
PlatformException(Error performing transaction, Timed out waiting for Task, null)`

Comment: this is the only message I get when the app crashes

Comment: PlatformExceptions are tricky if they are not propagated to the Dart side. There is an issue (or more than one) to make them available in Dart.